# Cakephp : 404 - File or directory not found after deploying on the windows server

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, http-status-code-404, cakephp-2.1

i have built a webapp on Cakephp 2.3 on my localhost .in my localhost the url of my website was like that

```
         localhost/Cakephp/
```

when i typed this address in my browser the url becomes like this

```
         localhost/Cakephp/login
```

it is redirecting to the login page

now i have deployed my app into an online server so now i am getting this error on accessing the following url

**url**

```
       http://www.webapp.com/login
```

**error**

**404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is        temporarily unavailable.**

Comment: And if you try " http://www.webapp.com/Cakephp/login " ?

Comment: nope i upload all the contents/files of Cakephp into my online server ... i didnt upload the folder ... and if it is the problem then it wont redirect me to the login page

Comment: That was just to be sure. Have you checked the file permissions and htaccess ?

Comment: nope i didnt know about the file permission and htaccess... i didnt change anything too

Comment: Sorry, I'm from France and it's so hot today, hard to stay in front of the computer. Have you tried to start from a fresh install on your server ? To see if the problem comes from the server or the framework

Comment: well i have downloaded cakephp and installed the cakephp folder on the server and cakephp is running fine .. dont know why my app isn't working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

URL rewriting is not working by default on IIS. You will have to [set it up](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).
You will have to create WebConfig files and set it up there.

Personally I find hosting PHP Apps on Windows a sort of "going against the flow" because:

- PHP was created to work within a Unix/Linux environment
- Afterwards it was ported to Windows
- Configuration and maintenance tend to be easier (for me at least) under Unix/Linux
- Some tasks that are trivial under Unix/Linux require more coding under an IIS intance (file storage for example needs some Windows specific COM objects if the server utilizes users and groups)
- The Url Rewriting is set up on 4 lines in 2 files in Apache. In IIS it takes several hundred lines of xml...
- Oh yes, and Microsoft sucks :D (Yes, they do!)

Anyway this is my personal opinion (backed up with some bad experiences). I am not saying that IIS is a bad web server - on the contrary it is good, just not good enough for PHP Apps.

Comment: Well, it's indeed a problem with the `.htaccess` then ? :)

Comment: No since he seems to be using IIS.